# Background images not loading when used in media queries

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pretty standard MVC template I'm using for a project. On a view in my project, I am trying to display a different background image depending on my screen width. The problem is that if I wrap the CSS in media queries then push the content up to a development server, my background images don't load. I don't have this problem in localhost though. I'm using Bootstrap in my project, but this particular CSS is written in a separate file. Also, this project sits in another project on my server.

```
/Root Project
 --My Project
```

CSS:

```
html {
background: url(/Images/img1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-ms-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
html {
    background: url(/Images/img2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    .center-margin {
    margin-top: 30%;
    }
    .header-text {
    color: black;
    }
}
```

The header in my HTML has the following metadata tags:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

After I took the media query off the first `html` block in my CSS, it started displaying again. The second block wrapped in the media query won't display. The other CSS inside the media query displays, so its just the background image that is giving me issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working. You should make sure that your image resources are uploaded to your server in the correct directory. Also, typically for loading URLs you're going to want to put them in quotes.

```
html {
  background: url("http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  htm

l {
    background: url("http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .center-margin {
    margin-top: 30%;
  }
  .header-text {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGQXNE) of this working with images hosted online.

Comment: I went up to my server to verify that the images are actually there and they are. I also put quotes around my urls, pushed the changes up to the server and still the same result.

Comment: Are you positive the images are in the same relative location to the source URL as you have on your localhost? Your code is not the problem, if anything play with the file path to make sure it is retrieving the files from the correct directory.